# Example of a $ \mathbb{Q} $-factorial, CM normal, projective, Mori dream space $ Z $ such that $ \operatorname{Cox}(Z) $ is integral and not CM

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, birational-geometry

Does anyone know an example of a $ \mathbb{Q} $-factorial, normal, Cohen Macaulay, projective, Mori dream space $ Z $ over a field $ k $ of arbitrary characteristic such that the Cox ring of $ Z $ is an integral domain and not Cohen Macaulay?

Comment: I believe that is true of every *very general* Abelian variety $Z$ of dimension $\geq 2$ (so that the Picard group is cyclic).

Comment: Forgive me as I don't know much about Abelian varieties.  Do you have a proof that every very general Abelian variety of dimension $ \ge 2$ satisfies these requirements?  I am very curious.

Comment: This is well-known, perhaps first proved by Bruns and Herzog (perhaps it was known earlier).  One reference is Proposition 3.2 of the following article of Axel Staebler: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.5365.pdf

Comment: The picard number might be 1, but surely the Picard group is not cyclic?