# Example of a ruled, CM, $ \mathbb{Q} $-factorial, normal, Mori dream space whose Cox ring is integral but not CM,

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, birational-geometry

This question is related to one I asked here in [Example of a $ \mathbb{Q} $-factorial, CM normal, projective, Mori dream space $ Z $ such that $ \operatorname{Cox}(Z) $ is integral and not CM](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458621/example-of-a-mathbbq-factorial-cm-normal-projective-mori-dream-space).  In that question I asked if anyone knew of an example of a Cohen Macaulay, $ \mathbb{Q} $-factorial, normal, Mori dream space $ Z $ over a field $ k $ of arbitrary characteristic such that the Cox ring of $ Z $ is integral, but not Cohen Macaulay.

Jason Starr gave an answer that every Abelian variety $ Z $ of very general type such that $ \dim(Z) \ge 2 $ satisfies this property.  In my case it is very relevant that the underlying variety $ Z $ is ruled, i.e., it is birational to a variety of the form $ Y \times \mathbb{P}^{1}_{k} $.  Does anyone know of a $ \mathbb{Q} $-factorial, ruled, Cohen Macaulay, projective, Mori dream space $ Z $ such that the Cox ring of $ Z $ is integral and not Cohen Macaulay?

Comment: If $Y$ is an Abelian variety of dimension $\geq 2$ whose Picard group is cyclic, then $Y\times \mathbb{P}^1$ is a ruled, smooth, projective Mori dream space, yet the Cox ring is not Cohen-Macaulay.