# Reference request showing that a very general Abelian variety $ A $ of genus $ g>1 $ has cyclic class group with ample generator

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, abelian-varieties, birational-geometry

In [Example of a $ \mathbb{Q} $-factorial, CM normal, projective, Mori dream space $ Z $ such that $ \operatorname{Cox}(Z) $ is integral and not CM](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458621/example-of-a-mathbbq-factorial-cm-normal-projective-mori-dream-space) I asked for an example of a Cohen Macaulay, normal, projective, Mori dream space $ Z $ such that $ \operatorname{Cox}(Z) $ is integral and not Cohen Macaulay.

Jason Starr pointed out that if $ Z $ is a very general Abelian variety of dimension $ g>1 $ should have a cyclic class group with ample generator $ \mathcal{L} $ so that $ \operatorname{Cox}(Z) $ should be graded and isomorphic to the section ring $ \oplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} H^{0}(Z, \mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}) $.  Then the result that such Abelian varieties are not Arithmetically Cohen Macaulay should be an example.  Does someone have a reference that a) very general Abelian varieties of dimension $ g>1 $ have a cyclic class group with ample generator and b) that such varieties exist.

Comment: I think you may be conflating the expressions "very general" and "of general type", which have little to do with each other. Only the first was meant.

Comment: Also, what you call the "class group" is the Néron-Severi group.

Comment: @WillSawin you are right.  Looking back at that post I realized that I was conflating the notions.  I will change it.

Comment: @WillSawin the change has been made.

Comment: @abx No, I mean the class group.  The Neron-Severi group is the group $ \operatorname{Div}(Z) $ modulo numerical equivalence.  The class group is the group $ \operatorname{Div}(Z)/\operatorname{PDiv}(Z) $.  The Cox ring of $ Z $ is graded by the class group and not the Neron-Severi group unless there are some circumstances present under which the two are isomorphic.  I may be misunderstanding Jason Starr's argument if his argument necessitates that it be the Neron-Severi group.

Comment: @abx I must confess that I don't know that much about Abelian varieties and when I read Jason Starr's argument I wasn't sure if he misconstrued the ring of global sections of a projective variety with the Cox ring.  The reason was that the paper he reference in the conversation thread showed that under such circumstances if $ (A,\mathcal{L}) $ is a principally polarized, Abelian variety then the ring $ \oplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} H^{0}(A, \mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}) $ is not Cohen Macaulay (cont).

Comment: The Cox ring is in graded by a finitely generated Abelian group in general, i.e., the class group.  Therefore in general it is not graded.  Jason Starr mentioned that the Picard group is cyclic in the aforementioned post.  Since the variety in question would be $ \mathbb{Q} $-Cartier, the Class group would also be cyclic with an ample generator.  I figured that due to the high caliber of Jason Starr's work that he was not mistaking the Cox ring for the ring of global sections though (cont).

Comment: Nonetheless it is imperative that the class group be cyclic.

Comment: @Schemer1 You fixed the text of your question, but the title still refers to an abelian variety of general type. It would probably be a good idea to fix that, too.

Comment: A nonzero abelian variety $A$ never has Picard group isomorphic to $\mathbf Z$, because it contains the dual abelian variety $\mathbf{Pic}^0_A$. This even holds for an elliptic curve, which by the citation that Jason Starr gave in the [other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458621/example-of-a-mathbbq-factorial-cm-normal-projective-mori-dream-space#comment1188806_458621) is nonetheless arithmetically Cohen–Macaulay.

Comment: Thank you @R.vanDobbendeBruyn

Comment: I have fixed the question.  Thank you @JoeSilverman.